# How Unzip a Folder At Jelatics?

Tags: unzip, jelastic

i'm new here. I would like to know how can i unzip a uploaded folder at apache / jelastic / Wordpress, like a folder with all my plugins or images.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy a project from an archive directly from the Jelastic dashboard - see [Upload and Deploy your PHP Application](http://docs.jelastic.com/whole-project-deploying) in the official docs - but in this case the archive should contain your entire site (e.g. WordPress and all desired plugins, themes etc.).

Alternatively you can upload your archive ([via the dashboard](https://docs.jelastic.com/application-configuration#docs-internal-guid-b74b4f54-5e1a-8d65-8929-3e1ae16b5171), [FTP/S](https://docs.jelastic.com/ftp-ftps-support), or [SFTP](https://docs.jelastic.com/ssh-protocols)) and then [connect to your node via SSH](https://docs.jelastic.com/ssh-overview).

Then you can use a command like this to extract the archive in the desired location:

`tar -xzvf archive.tar.gz`

EDIT: Since you mentioned zip archive, the command to use would be:

`unzip archive.zip`